# Keycloak Authorization Service - Dynamic Resource and Resource attributes

Tags: spring-boot, authorization, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot application, and I am using Keycloak's Authorisation Services.

Let's say I have a Report called `Report1`, with id `1`, created by `user1`.

The URL to access the resource would be `/app/{reportId}`. To access the report one will use `/app/1`

I want to restrict access to this url to the owner/creator of the report only (`user1`). Since this is kind of "dynamic" url, and the ID is not determined beforehand, I can't create a resource with static url (`app/1`) in Keycloak.

I would like to introduce a JS policy something like:

```js
    var context = $evaluation.context;
    var identity = context.identity;
    var permission = $evaluation.permission;
    var resource = <Report1>

    if (resource.<created_by_user_id> == identity.id) {
        $evaluation.grant();
    }
```

From the above code:

- `Report1` should be determined dynamically from DB
- `created_by_user_id` is an attribute of Report1 which contains `user1`

Any ideas?

Comment: how did you end up solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic url when creating resources are supported, that I know of.
Regarding the resource attributes, you can use something like this:

```
var attributes = resource.getAttributes();
```

You could attach a dedicated attribute, like ownership, where the value is the creator (user1).